# Redirect to page after login and back to page

Tags: angular, navigation, router

I have the following setup:

1) A user logs in to a page using his credentials.

2) When the user selects a specific option, he is redirected to a page of mine where he has to perform some actions. This page currently is run on `localhost:4200`

3) When the user finishes his actions, he pressed is button and he must be redirected to the previous page he was logged in.

The problem is, when I try to redirect to the last page, instead of the screen I want to show, I get the login page again.

Below is my code

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormComponent } from './views/form/form.component';
import { ServiceInfoComponent } from './views/service-info/service-info.component';
import { CreatedServiceComponent } from './views/created-service/created-service.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'service-info', component: ServiceInfoComponent },
    { path: 'created-service', component: CreatedServiceComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'service-info', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'form', component: FormComponent } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Can you please provide the app-routing code

Comment: You can find the app-routing code [here](https://pastebin.com/4TfD0mhH)